# set element width or height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I want to assign element's width to itself. For example, I have a div with content and I want to assign `style="width:..."` it.
Then in jQuery I do:

```
elem.width(elem.width());
```

Which looks for me totally wrong since it looks like how can I set the width by getting it..

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: why would you want or need to do this?

Comment: For me it looks fine, since getting and setting is done differently in jQuery. While getting the width is mostly calculated, when setting -- it is set explicitly with styles.

Comment: do you want in jQuery or Javascript...??

Comment: @Prasath K: I don't care. jQuery IS JavaScript.

Comment: when you're not passing a parameter to set the width, what's left but to just return the width that's already set?

Comment: Why do feel bad about this? Those are 2 different functions. One is without parameter and second with parameter, what's wrong with that? I suppose it would look better with properties, but still I don't see why anyone would do such assignments :-)

Comment: @mariozski: I need to set the width of a ul in order to position in horizontal center.

Comment: @mariozski I think he's got the right spirit. jQuery is all about doing redundant things...

Comment: Try out my answer .. I think it may help you...

Comment: Goodness. You practically have the answer in your hands. Just call element again with "elem.width( newwidth )" and the width has been set to the "newwidth"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
document.getElementById('divName').style.width = '10px';
```

Comment: I am not asking how to do something. I am asking if this is the right way and whether this is wrong or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$(function() {
  $("#mainTable").width(100).height(200);
});
```

This has 2 changes, it now uses .width() and .height(), as well as runs the code on the document.ready event.

Without the $(function() { }) wrapper (or $(document).ready(function() { }) if you prefer), your element may not be present yet, so $("#mainTable") just wouldn't find anything to...well, do stuff to.

Comment: 100 and 200 are static but you need to place dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

Better to add CSS using JQuery following way :

$(function() {
 $("#test").css({
   width : '30px',
   height : '30px'
 });
});

Comment: I am not asking how to do something. I am asking if this is the right way and whether this is wrong or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the style, you could use jQuery's [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$('.element').css('width', $('.element').width());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple elements with the same class (but different widths) you can do this:

```
$('.yourClass').width( function(id, width) {
    return width;
});
```

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-functionindex--width) for explanation.

Comment: I am not asking how to do something. I am asking if this is the right way and whether this is wrong or not.

Comment: You asked for a better way, since there are lots of answers/comments here telling you that it isn't wrong what you're currently doing I just gave you another example covering a case you might not have considered yet, e.g. setting `style="width:..."` of multiple, different sized elements with the same selector.